# ReferenceError: Vue is not defined when importing an external js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, yarnpkg

I'm using this package https://github.com/hartwork/vue-tristate-checkbox in my vue js component by installing it via yarn add hartwork/vue-tristate-checkbox

in my Vue js component i import it like this:

import 'vue-tristate-checkbox/vue_cycling_tristate_checkbox_native'

Now i run tests: yarn test

i get an error that the "ReferenceError: Vue is not defined" so i import it here manually like this import Vue from 'vue' just for test case.

And in this level every thing is working well but the tests not.

Because after importing the vue instanse i got another error:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I don't know is there is any way to work around this?

Answer (score -2):

You need to install the library, but in the readme there isn´t the command for npm install.
Maybe you could try npm install vue-tristate-checkbox

Comment: I already said i installed it using yarn: yarn add hartwork/vue-tristate-checkbox

Comment: I´m sorry, my fault. And the problem is Vue, not the library.

Comment: No problem, yeah i think so. i'm not sure